# Jquery on hover and out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-hover

I am trying to hide a div whenever I will hover over it and show another one in the same place.. And when I take the mouse out of that.. the previous `div` will be shown and this `div` will be hidden...

```
$(document).ready(function(){



      $('#hover_tutor').hover(
         function () {
           $('#hover_tutor').hide();
           $('#hover_tutor_hidden').show();
         }, 
         function () {
           $('#hover_tutor').show();
         $('#hover_tutor_hidden').hide();
         }
     );

   });



  <div id="hover_tutor">Blah</div>
  <div id="hover_tutor_hidden" style="display:none;">Bleh</div>
```

But on hovering the `hover_tutor`... something is happening.. It's jumping up and down.. I don't know what's wrong...

Comment: why you add 2 function?

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira 2 functions is more or less what is needed, but attached to different classes` mouse events

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use `.mouseenter` event for `#hover_tutor` div and `.mouseleave` for `#hover_tutor_hidden` div:

```
$('#hover_tutor').mouseenter(function () {
       $(this).hide();
       $('#hover_tutor_hidden').show();
     });

 $('#hover_tutor_hidden').mouseleave(function () {
       $('#hover_tutor').show();
     $(this).hide();
     }
 ).mouseleave();//trigger mouseleave to hide second div in beginning
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nuLubyut/)**

Comment: This could be revised with more explanation and be a featured answer. Excellent example.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use toggle method instent of hide/show on hover event

```
<div id="hover_tutor" style="display: block;">Blah</div>
<div id="hover_tutor_hidden" style="display: none;">Bleh</div>

  $('#hover_tutor').hover(
     function () {
      $('#hover_tutor').toggle();
       $('#hover_tutor_hidden').toggle();
     });
```

Working demo
http://jsfiddle.net/ivyansh9897/8jgjvkqk/

Answer (score 1):

If you do have the flexibility to modify your html little bit using class attribute there's a better way. Use [***.toggle()***](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to alter the state of your element on both [***mouseover***](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) and [***mouseleave***](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/).

***HTML :***

```
<div id="hover_tutor" class="hello">Blah</div>
<div id="hover_tutor_hidden" class="hello" style="display:none;">Bleh</div>
```

***jQuery :***

```
$(".hello").on("mouseover mouseleave", function(){
    $("#hover_tutor").toggle();
    $("#hover_tutor_hidden").toggle();
});
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/vn9cwwtn/)

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
$('#hover_tutor').hover(function () {
           $(this).hide();
           $('#hover_tutor_hidden').show();
         });

 $('#hover_tutor_hidden').hover(function () {
           $('#hover_tutor').show();
         $(this).hide();
         }
     ));
```